# webview Implement Load Cache When Offline

Tags: android, caching, webview, local, offline

thanks in advance I am trying to implement webview caching mechanism to a webview apk that I have done but I cant make this work.
I am very very inexpert.

#### Ok, I made some changes now i have no errors but the app still not working offline..

### This is my entire code:

#### AndroidManifiest.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="uy.celular.service.HR" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <activity android:name="A" >
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="activity_a" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>
    <application

        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

          </application>

</manifest>
```

#### MainActivity.java

```
package uy.celular.service.HR;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(uy.celular.service.HR.R.layout.activity_main);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
        webView.setInitialScale(110);

        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                WebView webView = new WebView(context);
                webView.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(5 * 1024 * 1024); // 5MB
                webView.getSettings().setAppCachePath(getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath());
                webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
                webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
                webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT); // load online by default

                if (!isNetworkAvailable()) { // loading offline
                    webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
                }
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return false;
            }
        });

        webView.loadUrl("http://www.celularservice.uy/p/mobile.html?m=1#trab");
        webView.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient(){


            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            //hide loading image
            findViewById(R.id.imageLoading1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //show webview
            findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }});
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }


}
```

#### MyAppWebViewClient.java

```
package uy.celular.service.HR;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.content.Context;

public class MyAppWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    public Context context;
    public boolean isNetworkAvailable() {

        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) this.context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
    }
    @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (url != null && url.startsWith("http://www.celularservice.uy/p/wp.html?m=1")) {
                view.getContext().startActivity(
                        new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
                return true;
            }
        if (url != null && url.startsWith("https://")) {
            view.getContext().startActivity(
                    new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
            return true;
        }
        if( url.startsWith("http:") || url.startsWith("https:") ) {
            return false;
        }

        else if (url.startsWith("tel:")) {
            Intent tel = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(url));
            view.getContext().startActivity(tel);
            return true;
        }
        else if (url.startsWith("sms:")) {
            Intent sms = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse(url));
            view.getContext().startActivity(sms);
            return true;
        }

        else if (url.startsWith("mailto:")) {
            Intent mail = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            mail.setType("application/octet-stream");
            mail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"celularservice.uy@gmail.com"});
            view.getContext().startActivity(mail);
            return true;
        }
        return true;

    }



}
```

remember i am new in this, please be expesific whit the answer

Answer (score 0):

`getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)` requires context. You either need pass the context to the `WebViewClient` or make the `WebViewClient` an inner class of the activity

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer, now the app run but srill not working offline, i update the Question. please be especific i am very new

Comment: Have you tried `LOAD_CACHE_ONLY` when there is no network available? Also do you know if the server sets some expiry on the content? If that is the case then you may also have to change the server implementation

Comment: can you say me what have to change? becouse i am totally new.. and can we force to save the page to the sdcard and when offline load from there?  thankss

Comment: Take a look at this. It explains what headers you can set on your server side to enable caching in the webview. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/increasing-application-performance-with-http-cache-headers

Comment: i put   <meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="public"/> in head but nothing change.. i thin the problem is in the code

Comment: But you did not set the age.

Comment: Have a look at it here as well. http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9

Answer (score 0):

Replace these:

```
webView.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(5 * 1024 * 1024); // 5MB     
webView.getSettings().setAppCachePath(getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath());
webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT); // load online by 
if (!isNetworkAvailable()) { // loading offline
webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
}
```

with

```
webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
```

You are good to go. I'd recommend not using webView as `WebView` variable. And, also, the `setAppCacheMaxSize` has been deprecated.